# Is there a way to use translateZ on an element without it automatically antialiasing all nested text?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I'm doing some simple transitions in my page (basic stuff like fades with opacity, background color changes, and border radius updates) and experiencing some flicker, both in the elements I'm animating and other unrelated elements on the page. Generally the quick fix for something like this is to add `translateZ(0)` to the element that you're animating, but in Webkit when you do this it seemingly automatically sets all nested text to `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`.

This is an undesired effect for me as I frequently use `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` and `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` throughout my pages to ensure my text is looking its best when it can.

Is there any way to avoid this side-effect of using `translateZ(0)`? FYI: this same thing happens when applying `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`.